# Is there "cache friendliness" for writing access?

Tags: c++, caching

Am writing code that fills a massive vertex buffer for procedural mesh generation (on CPU). This is fairly time critical.
Among other data, each vertex buffer consists of coordinates (X, Y, Z) as well as a normal vector (Xn, Yn, Zn).
Those are technically computed from fairly well separable code blocks.

My question is, should I write a loop to set all coordinates and then in another loop, set all normal vectors?
Or should I combine the two loops to ensure that all the indices within the vertex buffer are set one after another?

So is there a caching mechanism when writing consecutive array elements, or is that only for reading?

Comment: Benchmark and find out. If you're doing sequential memory access that's generally better than random, or working back and forth between multiple contiguous sets of data.

Comment: The only way to really know is to try both and get the results.  The two things you want to strive for is hot data and hot instructions.  That means that you are constantly accessing pre-fetched data and instructions.  If you can do that, then you normally see a speed increase.

Comment: Generally for writing really large amounts of data to ram keep successive writes within a cache line for max write throughput. You will be limited by the time it takes to write the cache line to physical ram. If ram writes are scattered, it gets more complicated. L1,2,3 cache will adsorb some of it up to a point and you may be more limited by calculation time. Worth it to do a bit of experimenting to get an intuitive feel for any given hardware platform. As @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica says, you have to measure. Plan on it.